# Add nanosecond Value in DateTime Class Constructor

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

When I have a value represent Date and time with **Accuracy in seconds exceeds milliseconds** How Can I add This Value into `DateTime`Class Constructors? Since the Max Value in Millisecond with range 0 through 999.

For Example this Time 17:29:35.1012663 have more Accuracy in second and I cannot add this Value in any version of Constructors related to DateTime Class!

```
var Date = new DateTime(2000, 02, 02, 17, 29, 35, 1012663);
Console.WriteLine(Date);
```

The output: *System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException*

Could anyone guide me How to add this value into `DateTime` Object?

Answer (score 2):

```
public DateTime(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second, int millisecond);
```

in this `DateTime` method the expected value for `int millisecond`is between 0 and 999 and you get error for this.

And for nanoseconds; `DateTime.Ticks` resolution is 100 nanoseconds. You can set the ticks with `DateTime.AddTicks`.

**NOTE :** AddTicks (and the other Add* methods) does not alter the DateTime, but returns a new object. So you should use as below;

```
date = date.AddTicks(...)
```